# each() with counter - const names

Tags: javascript, jquery, constants

I am trying to loop through some HTML elements, extract the content and set them as a const value with the index number like this...

```
jQuery('.myitems').each(function (index) {

    const myitem + index = [jQuery(this).text()];
    console.log(myitem + index);

});
```

This is not working, can anyone tell me the correct way to achieve?

Comment: "Isn't working" is not a technical description. What isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use object instead of count. And your code will be broken.
See the following solution.

```
jQuery('.myitems').each(function (index) {
    const count = {}
    count[myitem + index] = [jQuery(this).text()];
    console.log(count[myitem + index]);

});
```

Comment: Because I don't know exactly what the content of myItem, is it an object or number or string. It's just a suggestion. If myitem is an object, he can do myitem[item]

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt you store the values in an array instead?

```
const myitem = [];
jQuery('.myitems').each(function (index) {

    myitem[index] = jQuery(this).text();
    console.log(myitem[index]);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you're attempting in JS. An alternative would be to populate an array with the values by using `map()`:

```
var arr = $('.myitems').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

If you still want to use the `'myitem' + index` prefix on the values then you could instead use an object:

```
var obj = {};
$('.myitems').each(function(i) {
  obj['myitem' + i] = $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have first set constant and then on looping I have set value with index number. Currenlty , I have made output on console. You can check it. Let me know if you do not understand

```
const staff=[];

            $('.staff').each(function(index){

                staff[index]=$(this).text();
            })
            console.log(staff);
```